# Problem with index when using tex4ebook and sanitize-umlaut

Tags: indexing, tex4ht, tex4ebook

I used the package sanitize-umlaut for more convenient use of indexing in german. But producing an ebook the index lacks links to the index entries.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{filecontents}{sanitize-umlaut-file.ist}
actual '=' % as replacement for @
quote '!' % as replacement for "
level '>' % as replacement for ! 
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\ifdefined\HCode
%\usepackage[texindy,noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\else
%\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\fi
\usepackage{sanitize-umlaut}% Für Umlaute in index
\makeindex[options=-s sanitize-umlaut-file.ist -g]

\begin{document}

Über den Wolken\index{Über den Wolken}
muss die Freiheit wohl grenzenlos sein\index{muss die Freiheit wohl grenzenlos sein}
Übung macht den Meister\index{Übung macht den Meister}

\clearpage
\printindex
    
\end{document}
```

Do I lack any code? Or is there some new code necessary to make `tex4ebook` compatible with `sanitize-umlaut`?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a `make4ht` build file to get the index working, as we need special commands to prepare auxiliary files to be in the correct form. In your case, the build file can look like this:

```lua
Make:htlatex {} 
Make:makeindex {options = "-s sanitize-umlaut-file.ist -g"} 
Make:htlatex{}
```

The `Make:makeindex` command should run `makeindex` command. You can also try `Make:xindex` or `Make:xindy`, which should have a better support for German than Makeindex. See more info in this [how-to on indexing with TeX4ht](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#indexing).

For example, to use `xindex`, use this build file:

```lua
Make:htlatex {} 
Make:xindex {language="de"}
Make:htlatex{}
```

You will need to remove the `sanitize-umlaut` package from your document, as `xindex` expects UTF-8 input.

Compile using:

$ tex4ebook -e build.lua filename.tex

This is the resulting index:

[image]

Comment: Ok. I could not make it work - I am confused by these numerous makeindex, xindy, texindy, xindex, imakeidx - and all the different options to bind santize-umlaut.ist in it. the -s option is not universal, and makeindex and xindy and texindy have their own meal of options as it seems to me. Any support to get me oriented?

Comment: @Thomkrates I've used options from your code, they will not work with other index processors than `makeindex`. I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: I thought it could be possible to use sanitize-umlaut. So I need to do \index{Ueber den Wolken@Über den Wolken} which I like to avoid and just use \index{Über den Wolken} to get correct sorting. Without sanitize-umlaut this is not possible.

Comment: @Thomkrates I don't think you need to sanitize umlauts at all. You can use `xindex` also with the PDF output. It should be better than `makeindex` anyway.